# Is there any Java-Excel library that supports AutoFilter in Excel?

Tags: java, excel, autofilter

Last time I checked, Apache POI did not support this feature. If you know any solution that does, either free or commercial, please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache POI *does* support AutoFilter, though it's fairly recent functionality.

Simply call `setAutoFilter()` on your worksheet in POI with the cell range you want to filter. See documentation:
http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setAutoFilter%28org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress%29